# Circular imageview initially load as square in UITableViewCell - Xamarin.iOS

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, uiimageview

I am making my `UIImageView` as circles in my `UITableViewCell`. So I have done like this in `GetCell` method as below.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(_cellIdentifier);
        RemotesupportAgentData item = _tableItems[indexPath.Row];
        //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, _cellIdentifier);
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = (string)item.Attributes["Name"];

        cell.ImageView.SetImage(new NSUrl((string)item.Attributes["avatar"]), UIImage.FromBundle("contacts-32.png"));
        cell.ImageView.ClipsToBounds = true;
        cell.ImageView.Layer.CornerRadius = cell.ImageView.Frame.Width / 2;
        cell.ImageView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Green.CGColor;
        cell.ImageView.Layer.BorderWidth = (nfloat)2.0;

        return cell;
    }
```

My problem is, initially this image views load as squares when I scroll only it makes itself as circles. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the frame of `cell.ImageView` is zero at the initial time. It won't render to the actual size until it has finished displaying.

And I don't recommend you to place the configuration code in the cell's reuse method. This event will be called over and over again when the cell appears. We should only put the value setting stuff in that event due to the performance considering.

So firstly, create a new table view class and do some configurations there:

```
public class MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public MyCustomCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

        ImageView.ClipsToBounds = true;   
        ImageView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Green.CGColor;
        ImageView.Layer.BorderWidth = (nfloat)2.0;
    }

    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);

        // Your will get the actual size in the event
        if (ImageView.Layer.CornerRadius == 0)
            ImageView.Layer.CornerRadius = ImageView.Frame.Width / 2;
    }
}
```

Then, register it when you initialize the table view:

```
tableView.Source = new MyTableViewSource(list);
tableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(MyCustomCell), _cellIdentifier);
```

At last, your get cell method could be simply like this:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    MyCustomCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(_cellIdentifier) as MyCustomCell;
    RemotesupportAgentData item = _tableItems[indexPath.Row];

    cell.TextLabel.Text = (string)item.Attributes["Name"];

    cell.ImageView.SetImage(new NSUrl((string)item.Attributes["avatar"]), UIImage.FromBundle("contacts-32.png"));

    return cell;
}
```